# getting previous exon from gtf file-#R programming:

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the my selected exon cordinates(dataframe=my exons) and a gtf dataframe (dataframe=gtf). I am trying to first find my exons from the gft and then once found trying to extract the previous exon from the gft as output. i have given an example below.

## dataframe my exons

```
start   end exon_num    width   gene    geneid_exon_num_start_end
61178981    61179171    2   191 AHSA2   AHSA2 -2-61178981-61179171
243613671   243613739   7   69  AKT3    AKT3 -7-243613671-243613739
36952886    36953296    3   411 AATF    AATF -3-36952886-36953296
```

## dataframe gtf

```
start   end exon_num    width   gene    geneid_exon_num_start_end
61177472    61177618    1   147 AHSA2   AHSA2 -1-61177472-61177618
61178668    61179171    1   504 AHSA2   AHSA2 -1-61178668-61179171
61185526    61185618    1   93  AHSA2   AHSA2 -1-61185526-61185618
61178981    61179171    2   191 AHSA2   AHSA2 -2-61178981-61179171
36950214    36950405    2   192 AATF    AATF -2-36950214-36950405
37056601    37056858    2   258 AATF    AATF -2-37056601-37056858
36952886    36953296    3   411 AATF    AATF -3-36952886-36953296
19958014    19958571    4   558 AATF    AATF -4-19958014-19958571
```

## dataframe output

```
start   end exon_num    width   gene    geneid_exon_num_start_end
61177472    61177618    1   147 AHSA2   AHSA2 -1-61177472-61177618
36950214    36950405    2   192 AATF    AATF -2-36950214-36950405
```

I am using this in order to find my exons from the gtf, once found take the row above to get the previous exon.

```
previous_exon=gft[which(gtf$geneid_exon_num_start_end %in% myexons$geneid_exon_num_start_end)+c(-1),]
```

the problem is that, i gives (i.e, just one row above).

```
start   end exon_num    width   gene    geneid_exon_num_start_end
61185526    61185618    1   93  AHSA2   AHSA2 -1-61185526-61185618
37056601    37056858    2   258 AATF    AATF -2-37056601-37056858
```

I dont want this. if you see there are multiple previous exons with difefrent cordinates, so i want the row in which the end cordinate of the previous exon is samller than the start of my exon (see the required output). I have a huge dataframe so cant do one by one , so need help to keep this track and get the output.

Comment: Could you add some more detail to the desired rule you describe in the last paragraph? When you say "the row in which the end coordinate of the previous exon is smaller than the start of my exon" do you mean ANY row with the same gene where `end` is a smaller number? Or the same gene with the SMALLEST number? What if no row has a smaller number? Relying on order of rows can be difficult - if your rows were mixed up, could we write a rule that still finds the correct row?

Comment: @BrianStamper yes i mean within the same gene, get the row with the end cordinate smaller than the start cordinate of the my exon. Well there is no such situation where you dont find a smaller number. i have ordered my data frame on gene name and exon number.

Comment: For `AATF -2-37056601-37056858` there are three other `AATF` rows all of which have `end` numbers smaller than the `start` number `37056601`, which one should be chosen?